# What is the meaning of "Alibi"-JavaDoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I read about JavaDoc comments "containing only the signature of the method" referred to as "Alibi"-JavaDoc. I am not quite sure what that means. This is how I understand it:

```
/**
* Documented with JavaDoc.
*/
public interface IInterface 
{

    /**
    * Documented with JavaDoc.
    * @return Data.
    */
    public int getData();
}

// ...

// Implementation not documented with JavaDoc.
public class Impl implements IInterface
{
    // ....
    private int data;


    // Implementation not documented with JavaDoc.
    public int getData()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

Is that correct, or does it mean something else?

Comment: In english, *alibi* means a proof to something that exists. Applying the same definition here, I guess it refers to creating an interface to your class which contains only the methods declaration with its arguments, but not the implementation, which should be elsewhere. 
So yes, your example is correct.

Comment: a second meaning according [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alibi): An excuse, especially one used to avoid responsibility or blame.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger How would you apply that to a JavaDoc comment?

Comment: like doing an 'empty' JavaDoc comment so it is just there (containing only the signature is as good as being empty). For example to trick some code revision... but I never heard of 'alibi' JavaDoc, so it's only an interpretation of mine

Comment: Hmm, that could be possible.

Comment: hmm sounds like those automatically generated JavaDoc comments - just to 'I have added JavaDoc' because some style-tool refuses to build the project without it